# Creating multiple dropdown like in stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a dropdown menu like the one in this site. I want to make 3 things happen.

1. Make dropdown appear on click.
2. Only display one dropdown at a time, so clicking on another dropdown link will remove the displaying dropdown and add the dropdown you clicked on.
3. Removing displayed dropdown when clicking on the same dropdown link or clicking outside the dropdown.

I am not sure if I need a plugin or if the best way is to create this by writing your own code.
Here is my code and it works good but the only problem is that it dosen't remove the displayed dropdown when clicking on the same dropdown link.

```js
 $('a#menu1').click(function() {
   $("div#1").show();
  });
  $('a#menu2').click(function() {
   $("div#2").show();
  });
   $('a#menu3').click(function() {
   $("div#3").show();
  });

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = new Array();
    container.push($('.display_menu1'));
    container.push($('.display_menu2'));
    container.push($('.display_menu3'));
    
    $.each(container, function(key, value) {
        if (!$(value).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && $(value).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div.body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div.display_menu1 {
  display: none;
}

div.display_menu2 {
  display: none;
}

div.display_menu3 {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.display {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.display {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" method="POST" id='menu1' class="number">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" method="POST" id='menu2' class="number">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" method="POST" id='menu3' class="number">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="1" class="display display_menu1">
    This is dropdown-menu 1!
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="display display_menu2">
    This is dropdown-menu 2!
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="display display_menu3">
    This is dropdown-menu 3!
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Inside on click function check the style.display property of div. If it is "none" then call show() otherwise call hide()

Comment: You can use $("div#1").toggle() instead of $("div#1").show();

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i still don't manage to make it work. This is what happened when adding toggle. https://jsfiddle.net/4wc54rq5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good thing is to work with classes not with Ids .. so in my next example I'm using `data` attribute and use same class for all divs

```js
$('a[data-menu]').click(function() {
  var menu_num = $(this).data('menu');  // get the href data-menu attribute to get the div id from it
  $('.display_menu').not($('#'+menu_num)).hide(0); // hide all the divs but not the open one
  $('#'+menu_num).slideToggle(100);  // toggle the div its already shown .. this slideToggle will show/hide it by clicking the <a>
  $('li').not($(this).closest('li')).removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click',function (e)
{
// no need here for using array and .each() 
    if (!$('a[data-menu] , .display_menu').is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && $('a[data-menu] , .display_menu').has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('.display_menu').hide(0);
        $('li').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
div.body {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

div.display_menu {
  display: none;
}


ul {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.display {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.display {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.active{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="body">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" method="POST" id='menu1' class="number" data-menu="1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" method="POST" id='menu2' class="number" data-menu="2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" method="POST" id='menu3' class="number" data-menu="3">Menu 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="1" class="display display_menu">
    This is dropdown-menu 1!
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="display display_menu">
    This is dropdown-menu 2!
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="display display_menu">
    This is dropdown-menu 3!
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: I am now trying to add a background color on the dropdown list item when the dropdown is displaying but I don't manage to make it work. Do you maybe know how to do this too?

Comment: @Night83 answer updated .. You'll find the active class in css

Comment: Thanks again! I really appreciate your help! :D